# Use JavaScript variable as iframe src?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, var

I'm trying to use a JavaScript variable as the `src` in a `<iframe>`, the user will then be able to load other content by choosing `scr` in a menu, which changes the variable. the default src URL is `apps/start.php`.

Here some code from my `index.php`:

```
    <script>
        var appurl = "start.php";
        document.getElementById("app").src = "apps/" + appurl();
    </script>

    <iframe id="app" src="">

    </iframe>
```

The problem is that i can't get this first small part working... The `<script>` tag is in the `<head>`. And when the `src` is changing will the new document automatically load?

Comment: appurl is a variable containing a string, so I don't see why you should execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the page to load (note that this is only going to work when the iframe is on your domain)

```
window.onload = function(){
 var appurl = "start.php";
 document.getElementById("app").src = "apps/" + appurl;
};
```

Comment: Thanks now it works! But if the iframe content document is on another domain?

Comment: The iFrame is on your own domain, if you want to access the content of the iFrame of another domain, that is not possible. Because thats cross domain javascripting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Javascript is run before the iframe is there. Put your javascript below your iFrame or inside the document ready and it will work.

Example document onload:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        var appurl = "start.php";
        document.getElementById("app").src = "apps/" + appurl();
    }
</script>

<iframe id="app" src="">

</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        var appurl = "start.php";
        document.getElementById("app").src = "apps/" + appurl;
    }
</script>

<iframe id="app" src="">

</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
 var appurl = 'start.php';
 document.getElementById("app").src = "apps/" + appurl;
};
</script>
```